# Configure Portrait Mode at one place

Tags: android, screen-orientation, portrait

Is there a way to set Android Portrait mode on an application level like how we do in iOS as shown below ?

[image: Configure portrait mode in iOS]

I do not want to add

> android:configChanges="orientation"
>   android:screenOrientation="portrait"

on each Activity entry of the manifest
or add the following code

> setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

in each activity!
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this the same way you do it in iOS. The closest you can come to avoiding boilerplate code in each activity, is to create an Activity, let's say `PortraitActivity`, where you set orientation:

```
setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

in onCreate and make all your activities extend this activity.

Answer (score 0):

`configChanges` is unnecessary for requesting portrait orientation, but you have to add `screenOrientation="portrait"` at every activity on manifest or `"portraitSensor"` that will give both portrait and portraitInverse.